# How to let Eclipse know that launch configuration was changed?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In the class `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer` there is a method `isDirty()`. At the last line of it in the return statement there is `!fOriginal.contentsEqual(workingCopy)`. I want it to be `true`, but I don't know, how to make Eclipse think that launch configuration was changed?

I need to do be able to do it in any place in my custom launch configuration tab class, for example in `SelectionListeners` of some buttons. So how Eclipse understands whether the configuration was changed?

Comment: Would you mind showing us how you actually modify your workingCopy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal action for changes is to call the `AbstractLaunchConfigurationTab.updateLaunchConfigurationDialog()` method. This should deal with updating the dirty flags correctly.

Among other things this calls `LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.refresh()` which deals with the working copy being dirty.

Comment: I tried `updateLaunchConfigurationDialog()`, but it didn't work as I expect. Problem is in line I wrote in the question: `!fOriginal.contentsEqual(workingCopy)` in `LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.isDirty()` - it is `false`

Comment: It sounds like you are not setting anything in the configuration working copy to make it different from the original. Normally you would call `setAttribute` to change some value.

Comment: Yes, I dont do it. But is there any way to tell Eclipse that configuration was changed without setting any attribute?

Comment: No I don't think so. Attribute keys can be anything so you can just set a 'thisIsDirty' attribute.

Comment: Then how can I get working copy of configuration in any place to call setAttribute? What is the most correct way to do it?

Comment: As I recall when the `updateLaunchConfigurationDialog` call will call the tab `performApply` method with the `ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy` that you should update.

Comment: I love you man. Thank you so much, now I realized it was a bug in my `performApply`